How to remove the gap between the main content and sidebar in a flexbox layout?
I'm working on a web layout where I have a main content area and a sidebar, both placed within a flex container. However, I'm encountering an issue where there's a large gap between the left of the main content and the sidebar. Here's my HTML and CSS setup:
This is how it looks and you can see the gap between the sidebar and the map:
The main page
Despite setting padding: 0; and margin-left: 0; on the .main-content, there's still a noticeable gap between it and the sidebar. How can I remove this gap and ensure that the main content area fills the space next to the sidebar without any extra spacing?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Instead of the image, can you share a live link or a fiddle?

Actually, it is not live currently.

I shared all of the needed code, if you can help you. :)

Sorry, it is harder to detect the issue with the missing styles. Btw the issue seems simple. Check if the flex-basis property is correctly set or not. I am guessing the basis needs to be 100%.

What do you mean by "missing styles"?
I shared the CSS for the page.

Something like this, . the whole layout seems broken :)

The CSS code that I shared is the "index_page.css"

You got two nested .content-wrapper elements there - and both are getting margin-left: 250px applied. The outer one needs it, so that its content doesn't get overlapped by the fixed sidebar - but the inner one doesn't.

@CBroe, Actually, it is set to 0 as you can see. Where you saw that it is 250px?

I came in to say the same as CBroe. Check your dev tools. There's a media query on line 17 that's setting a left margin of 250px.

@ralph.m Where you saw it bro?
Can you show me?
I can not see it.

Open your devtools and click on <div class="content-wrapper">. You'll see the CSS rule and a big orange section highlighting the left margin.

Yes, but I can not see where in the CSS, the margin-left is 250px!?
I see that it is 0px.
What is wrong with me...
